# 2 Postgres Servers on local machine. How to uninstall or disassociate one?

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

Through some mishap I seem to have 2 separate Postgres servers on my local Ubuntu machine. PGAdmin connects to one (localhost:5432), which can also be reached with the terminal through: `sudo -u postgres psql postgres -W -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432`

The other "default" server can be reached through the terminal with just `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`

For other info, `locate bin/psql` returns:

> /usr/bin/psql
>
> /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/psql

I suspect the latter of those directories is the Postgres 9.5 instance I really want to use, and the one I want to associate with without needing to specify -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432. The other can be removed completely. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package manager to remove it.

From terminal, you can list the installed versions of PostgreSQL executing:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep postgresql
```

The ones with the format `postgresql-X` (where "X" is the version) is those to remove. You should be able to do it with the `apt purge` command.

For example, to remove the version `9.6`, you have to execute:

```
$ sudo apt purge postgresql-9.6
```

`/usr/bin/psql` should be a symbolic link to the most recent version installed (`/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/psql`).

Comment: If I don't specify the port and host in the cmd prompt, I connect to an instance that is different. If I create a database or table here, it does not show up in pgadmin or when connecting with the host and port, and vise versa.

Comment: "sudo -u postgres psql postgres" shows "psql (9.6.9)" in the terminal, and "sudo -u postgres psql postgres -W -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432" shows "psql (9.6.9, server 9.5.13)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)"

Comment: You mention you are on Ubuntu. What version?
Try executing this `apt list --installed | grep postgres'` ... what do you get?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. What I get from that list is here https://i.imgur.com/wlC3Ri4.png

Comment: And to answer your first question, executing ls -l /usr/bin/psql gives "lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Nov  8  2017 /usr/bin/psql -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper"

Comment: Yep. You have two versions installed. I update the answer ;)